# Preventing default iOS webpage drag with javascript and hammerJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, hammer.js

I am creating a simple web app that uses the new version of hammerJS for pinch zooming. I am having an issue with the default iOS page drag when a pinch starts. This seams to override the pinch event that I am attempting to capture. Any help stoping this while using hammerJS would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I have attempted to use event.preventDefault() to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `preventDefault` slightly differently to how you may be used to. Like so:

```
 $('#your_element').on('pinch', function(event) {
      event.gesture.preventDefault();
 });
```

See [this hammer.js example](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/9b185183a4c85559b38b4ebe67536cf90b1aa541/examples/drag.html#L57) for another example.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
```

Basically the user-scalable property controls if users are allowed to zoom the page. So once you disable it you can control the zoom with hammerJs.

More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_basics

Comment: It appears that the drag created by pinching is still captured by safari on iOS. This causes the page in the browser to drag down (not scroll). The web app does not have any scroll bars.

Comment: Weird... [preventDefault()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW24) should disable the pinch zoom

Answer (score 0):

What were you calling preventDefault on? I usually combine @Bertrand's answer with something like this

```
$(body).on('touchmove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```